# ¿Cómo corregir este fallo en consulta Update, en JavaFX con SQLite manager?

Tags: sql, javafx, sqllite

estoy haciendo una aplicacion usando Java FX y SQLite Manager.

Quiero que mi app tenga una opcion de cambiar la contraseña pero cuando pongo los valores correctos no se actualiza.
Os enseño mi codigo:
[image: CLASE MODELO]

[image: Metodo que evalua todas las posibilidades. Devuelve un string dependiendo del caso]

[image: Clase controlador]

[image: Metodo asignado a boton confirmar. Deberia escribir en un label un mensaje dependiendo del caso. En caso de fallo lo escribe correctamente.]

He debuggeado y me entra en el condicional if si todo está correcto. Lo que no entiendo es por qué en ese caso no se me actualiza el label ni se ejecuta correctamente la query.

Es la primera vez que publico algo aqui y la verdad que ando apurada porque entregoe sto mañana jajaja sé que es dificil que alguien lo vea pero bueno, muchas gracias de adelanto

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Como recomendación, el código no se comparte como imagen (se pone como texto), así como nadie te va a responder con imágenes para que tengas que transcribir código en ellas. Muchas veces, aquí se replica el problema reportado usando el código, lo que se hace imposible desde una imagen sin correr el riesgo de introducir otros errores u omitir el error original. PD. Evita usar mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor

Comment: @Alfabravo muchas gracias por toda la informacion :) lo tendré en cuenta para próximas publicaciones

Answer (score 1):

Vale, lo acabo de solucionar. Me daba este error:
[SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)

Y era porque en cada clase Model creaba una conexion pero no las cerraba.

Espero que ayude a alguien si le pasa lo mismo

Comment: Otra nota: puedes marcar tu propia respuesta (en un rato) como aceptada para que otros en el futuro sepan que esta es la solución a este tipo de problema.